# setter being called in a recursive loop

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript class, which goes:

```
class mockUser {
  constructor (
    location,
   ) {
    this.location = location;
  }

  set location (data) {
    this.location = data; // here's the problem
  }
}
```

But when I try to use the `set` keyword I get a warning, saying `Function location recurses indefinitely and can only end by throwing an exception`. Why is that?

I mean I could do

```
  setLocation (data) {
    this.location = data; // here's the problem
  }
```

But what's the point of `set` then?

I guess I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Set" means "when something tries to set this property, call this function".

So, by setting location inside the setter, you're calling the setter - hence the recursion.

Comment: So I actually don't have to create a setter? Just assign it like `obj.location='test'`? Or are setters good idea?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding. Setters are good for when you want an assigment to affect other properties of the object. A good example I saw was obj.fullName = "Joe Bloggs" would split the string around the space and populate the firstName and lastName properties - internally, the fullName property doesn't actually exist.